# Finding area under system of $4$ inequalities

Tags: inequality, area

Let $R$ be the region where all four of the following inequalities hold
$$x^2 \lt 2+y$$
$$x^2 \lt 2-y$$
$$y^2 \lt 2+x$$
$$y^2 \lt 2-x$$
Find the area of R.

I tried adding all these inequalities, and got $x^2 + y^2 \lt 4$. So it's a circle with radius $2$, thus area = $4 \pi$, which is the wrong answer. What is wrong with adding them up, and how should I approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Consider the inequalities $x < 1$ and $x < 3$ on the real line. Values of $x$ that satisfy both of these are exactly those that satisfy the first, right? But add the two together and you get $x < 4$. Every valid solution (i.e., number less than 1) satisfies that new inequality (i.e., it's also less than 4), but NOT every number satisfying the new inequality (e.g., x = 3) satisfies the first. You've just a 2D version of this. That means that the actual set you're looking for lies in the interior of a radius-2 circle, but may only be a small portion of it.

Comment: If you draw the figure using Geogebra, it is not a circle.

Comment: @JohnHughes Adding the two together gives $2x < 4$.

Comment: Thanks, Calvin. The same observation about the sets defined by the two holds (one is larger than the other), but OP my have doubts about my skills, given this stupid mistake. I shouldn't write answers when I'm late for a meeting. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For explaining this, I am assuming you have a basic understanding of sets, i.e., you know what a set is, what the solution set of an inequality is, what subset/superset is, etc. If you do not, you can easily find a video or article on the internet explaining it.

When given a system of inequalities, the sum or difference of any combination of those inequalities gives you a *new* inequality, which must *also* be satisfied by the solution set to the system of inequalities, but that necessarily does **not** mean that, the sum *is* the solution set. The sum contains simply gives you a different constraint on the solution set, which in certain cases might be useful. Which means the sum of the system of inequalities might contain extra solutions which aren't actually a solution to the system given, which makes the area bound by it larger than the actual area.

For example- I can ask you to check if the point $(5,1)$ is in the solution set of your system of inequalities.
$$
x^2 < 2+y \\
x^2 < 2-y \\
y^2 < 2+x \\
y^2 < 2-x
$$
you can add all four inequalities to get
$$x^2 + y^2 < 4$$

This tells you that every solution to the system of 4 inequalities must also be a solution to their sum. In other words, if $(5,1)$ is in the region bound by the four inequalities, it must along belong to the circle found by summing the inequalities. And since you clearly know that $(5,1)$ does not belong to the circle, you can confidently say that it is not in the solution set without having to check the point with each inequality.

If this seems different or counter-intuitive to the idea of systems of equations, it actually isn't

Suppose I asked you to solve a system of two equations.
$$
x + y = 4\\
x - 2y = 0
$$
Their sum:
$$
 2x - y = 4
$$
**contains** the solution to the system of linear equations, but every solution to the new equation is not a solution to the system of equations.

So with this I hope it's clear as to *why* your approach was incorrect and what you *actually* did when you added the inequalities together.

Now as for the right approach, I am not sure if there is an easy purely algebraic approach to your question. You can solve it using methods of calculus, but I don't know if you are familiar with calculus. If you are comfortable with calculus, let me know and I will explain the calculus approach to finding the area of the region.

EDIT: Explaining the Calculus approach to find the required area of the region.

Before we rotely apply integration, identifying two points of symmetry will simplify the question MASSIVELY.

**First**, we can note that, in any quadrant the area of the required region can be thought of the as the area of intersection of only two of the given inequalities. For example-

In Quadrant 1 (Q1) - The area bound by $x^2 < 2 - y$ and $y^2 < 2 - x$, will give us the PART of the TOTAL area in the first quadrant.

Side note, in case you want to think about it-
This is because each inequality has an *inverted inequality*, i.e., an inequality bounding the mirror image of the region bounded by any given inequality. [Might take sometime to sink in, read it a few times and definitely draw a rough graph, or graph it in Desmos]. So when the *mirror image inequality* makes it to the quadrant which we are concerned with, it ends up covering more area than the inequality we are looking at. So we may ignore the pair of *mirror image inequalities*, when dealing with any quadrant. My language might make it confusing to express what I am trying to say, so please draw a graph and try to understand what I am getting at.

This point of symmetry allows us to neglect two of the inequalities and just deal with only 1 pair while finding the area in any quadrant.

**Secondly,** we can also see the symmetry in all four inequalities and realise that, the area in each of the four quadrants is in fact equal. So we may just find the area enclosed in one of the quadrants, and multiply it by 4.

With these two points of symmetry, our problem becomes much less daunting and honestly straight forward.

Considering the first quadrant to find the area, we may do the following

First, we have to find the points of intersection of $x^2 < 2 - y$, $y^2 < 2 - x$, x-axis and y-axis.

You can find the points by looking at the graph and solving the appropriate pairs of equations to get the points of interest to be -
$(0,\sqrt{2}), (1,1), (\sqrt{2}, 0)$

From $(0,\sqrt{2})$ to $(1,1)$ We find the area under $y^2 = 2 - x$ and from $(1,1)$ to $(\sqrt{2}, 0)$, we find the area under $x^2 = 2 - y$

By doing a little rearrangement we get,

$y^2 = 2 - x \implies y = \sqrt{2-x}$ [This is okay without considering the negative root as we are only considering quadrant one]

$x^2 = 2 - y \implies y = 2 - x^2$

Now we may do the integration,

$$
\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{2-x}dx + \int_{1}^\sqrt{2} (2-x^2)dx
$$

These are pretty straight forward integrals to evaluate and require nothing beyond the basic integration formulae, so I will leave that to you.
But after you do it you must get,

$$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{2-x}dx + \int_{1}^\sqrt{2} (2-x^2)dx = \frac{8\sqrt{2}-7}{3}$$

If you have any further questions or doubts, please feel free to ask me!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am comfortable with calculus, so please tell me the approach with calculus. Thanks.

Comment: @acelixis I edited my answer, go through it and if you have any questions, feel free to ask me!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Look in the first quadrant and multiply by $4$

[image]